# JButton background on Nimbus LAF

Tags: swing, jbutton, nimbus

I use Nimbus LAF and I want to change the background of a simple `JButton`.

```
JButton jbutton = new JButton("test");
jbutton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

But it doesn't work, when I change the look and feel it works but it doesn't work in Nimbus.

How can i do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i should work, perhaps you have to call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jbutton);` after changing the LookAndFeel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nimbus uses Painter to paint the different Styles. By Default the Button has a gradient not a single Color. See Button:  [Nimbus Defaults List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

You can write your own Painter and override the default. Or you override the background color with the key "Button.background" and use the Default Painter.

```
UIDefaults overrides = new UIDefaults();
overrides.put("Button.background", Color.RED);
jbutton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides);
jbutton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", Boolean.TRUE);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jbutton);
```

Or if you want to change the Color for all Buttons, try:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
defaults.put("Button.background",  Color.RED);
```

Btw. The JButton bases on the Nimbus default key "nimbusBase", if you change this color :

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
defaults.put( "nimbusBase", Color.RED );
```

then you change everything that uses the nimbus defalut-blue or a secondary color into your new color, not only the Buttons.

I found a nice Nimbus Theme Creator, which can show the effect of changing a Nimbus Default Color to all Components: http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk