# Reusable Nimbus painting components (Focus ring)

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

I am creating custom Swing components and want to provide a `UI` that looks just like Nimbus.

I know how to access the `UIDefaults` colors, but can I reuse more code, particularly, is there a way to get an object that paints the **focus rings** (rectangular or oval, or even better, along any outline `Shape`) exactly like the other Nimbus components do? (without reinventing the wheel)

Comment: I think that same answer as here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9311409/714968

Comment: @mKorbel -- what do you mean? I know there is `UIManager`, but how do I retrieve the default Nimbus focus painter?

Comment: See if [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) can help you.

Comment: @Max. `"Tree.cellEditor"[Enabled+Focused].backgroundPainter` seems to be pretty what I need, although that just does Rectangles... Will probably need to bake my own it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't see any design decision in Nimbus to allow the reuse of painters for new components, and also I'm stuck on OS X with Java 6 and Nimbus being a moving (namespace) target, here is my solution which basically recreates what the Synth style is using:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class NimbusFocusBorder implements javax.swing.border.Border {
    private static final RoundRectangle2D rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Float();
    private static final Area area = new Area();

    private final float arcIn;
    private final float arcOut;

    public NimbusFocusBorder() {
        arcIn = arcOut = 0f;
    }

    public NimbusFocusBorder( float rounded ) {
        arcIn  = rounded * 2;
        arcOut = arcIn + 2.8f;
    }

    public void paintBorder( Component c, Graphics _g, int x, int y, int w, int h ) {
        if( !c.hasFocus() ) return;
        final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) _g;
        g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        g.setColor( /* NimbusHelper. */ getFocusColor() );
        rect.setRoundRect( x + 0.6, y + 0.6, w - 1.2, h - 1.2, arcOut, arcOut );
        area.reset();
        area.add( new Area( rect ));
        rect.setRoundRect( x + 2, y + 2, w - 4, h - 4, arcIn, arcIn );
        area.subtract( new Area( rect ));
        g.fill( area );

    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets( Component c ) {
        return new Insets( 2, 2, 2, 2 );
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() { return false; }

    // this actually looks up the color in UIDefaults
    // in the real implementation
    private Color getFocusColor() { return new Color( 115, 164, 209, 255 );}
}
```