# UIManager Won't Set Button Background

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus, uimanager

All, I am using java swing's UIManager to set this theme

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

This theme is terrible at differentiating disabled/enabled backgrounds for buttons, so I've been battling trying to get this to change the disabled background. Nothing is working for me. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, below are all my approaches so far

```
//My color constant
Color disabledButton = new Color(255,124,124);

//Maybe its these?
UIManager.put("Button.background", disabledButton);
UIManager.put("Button.foreground", disabledButton);

//No maybe this...
UIManager.put("Button.disabled", disabledButton);

//Okay how about this
UIManager.put("Button.disabled", "DerivedColor(color=255,124,124 parent=control offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,124,124");

//NO!!?!?! WELL FINE ILL SET THE BACKGROUND MYSELF
myButton.setBackground(disabledButton);
```

None of these work... where am I making an error?

Comment: _Why does UIManager suck?_ Most likely because you don't use it right. Yet, with so little code provided, it's pretty much impossible to tell what's wrong. Consider posting an MVCE

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Sure, adjusted my language. What other code would be helpful to explain a simple background change? What is an MVCE? Thanks.

Comment: [Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For info, Nimbus works in a quite different way compared to other default L&F provided by JRE. Try this to see what happens: `UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey",Color.RED);` See also this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary

Comment: Thank you! @GuillaumePolet This is what I've been looking for. I thought it would be in the UIManager or UIDefault sections or even the JButton sections... Didn't realize there was an entire Nimbus section.

Comment: Okay the only problem now is, I think I need to adjust `Button[Disabled].backgroundPainter` however that's a painter. This implies to me that I have to write my own painter and pass it in as opposed to adjusting a color inside the existing painter using `UIManager.get("Button[Disabled].backgroundPainter")`. Am I making this too complex? Is there another approach?

Comment: You may take a look at this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840599/jbutton-background-on-nimbus-laf

Comment: See also this alternate [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513).

Comment: @Constantin, `Didn't realize there was an entire Nimbus section.` - check out [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) and change the Look and Feel to Nimbus. The "System Colors" and "Miscellaneous" items contain the base colors used by Nimbus.