# JButton properties ignored by Nimbus, overriding border property

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, nimbus

I am having trouble to create a Button with specific properties when using Nimbus look and feel.

First of all, I am using this class to implement a Button in some columns of a JTable. https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/

[image: JButton in columns] Last 2 columns are empty JButtons

If I try to set this properties in the constructor I get no changes at all:

```
    renderButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    renderButton.setOpaque(false);
    renderButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

So I kept my research and I found how I was supposed to do this, since Nimbus was ignoring those properties. My next attempt:

```
    UIDefaults def = new UIDefaults();
    /*Properties Here*/
    renderButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", def);
    renderButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", true);
```

So I tried some, but I don't really know what names should I use:

```
    def.put("Button.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    def.put("Button.borderPainted", false);
    def.put("Button.background", Color.BLUE);
```

The background one is the only one that works for me, but I don't want that, I want the ones to remove borders.

One last thing, by doing this (setting last in false) and only this:

```
    UIDefaults def = new UIDefaults();
    renderButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", def);
    renderButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
```

I get no borders, but I do lose by last background (JTable stripped one):

[image]

As you see I plan to use images afterwards. I like this one better, but would rather prefer to keep the background.

BTW, maybe I shouldn't be doing this, and the problem is in other place.
Thanks for your help

Comment: That topic might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840599/jbutton-background-on-nimbus-laf

Comment: I already checked it, and it does help. Indeed, there was the property Button.background and that is the only one that works, I wonder which are the names of the properties related to borders.

EDIT: Just found the properties, but not what I expected

Comment: I'd be use Renderer only for striping, in Related (bottom, right side) shoud be a few attempts in SSCCE/MCVE form, the effort is not worth it ...

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the images getting rid of the background. Try editing the picture files and erasing all the white that isn't part of the object the picture is part of. Then the background should show with the pictures.

Comment: The background of the images is already transparent so the problem is not there.